# How do I install the syslinux package on Debian Stretch?

Tags: debian, apt, raspbian

I've installed Raspbian Stretch and run the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

When I try installing `syslinux` I get this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install syslinux -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package syslinux is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'syslinux' has no installation candidate
```

I want `syslinux` because when I try to run `mkwinpeimg` I get the following error

```
$ mkwinpeimg --windows-dir=/mnt/windows7 win7pe.img
ERROR: To make a bootable disk image of Windows PE, we need the "syslinux"
program, but it doesn't seem to be installed.  Please install the "syslinux"
package to continue, or try using the --iso option to make an ISO image instead
of a disk image.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://packages.debian.org/stretch/syslinux

Answer (score 3):

You can install syslinux with

```
sudo apt-get install syslinux-common -y
```

If you want to know what the other available packages of syslinux are you can search either by writing `sudo apt-get install syslinux` and hit <kbd>TAB</kbd> a few times or by typing `sudo apt search syslinux`.

Comment: Although this maybe "installed" syslinux-common, it still doesn't let me run `mkwinpeimg` and spits the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The [`syslinux`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/syslinux) package is only available for `amd64` and `i386`.

The package `wimtools` provide the `mkwinpeimg` command:

```
sudo apt install wimtools
```

Comment: Ah. So what's that mean exactly? It's only available on 64-bit and Itanium chipsets?

Comment: @gh0st the `syslinux-common` can be an alternative as the first proposed answer say.

Comment: The Debian package `syslinux-common` is not exactly an alternative for package `syslinux`. The former contains the components of the SYSLINUX bootloader that can be copied to a media to make it bootable in x86 BIOS style. But to actually install a working SYSLINUX bootloader onto a media in Linux, you'll need to run the `/usr/bin/syslinux` binary - which is in the latter package, and it is only available for the 64- and 32-bit x86 architectures. Apparently the developer and/or the packager did not expect that someone might want to use ARM hardware to build x86 boot media.